# Is it possible that a space which isn’t an affine variety is the union of countable affine varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is distinct from other questions on the topic about unions as I am specifying it is a union of countable varieties. Is there any simple (or more abstract) example of this? Or is it not possible that the union of countable affine varieties is not an affine variety? My gut feeling is that the union should be affine but would like to be sure of it

Answer (score 1):

Take $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb A^1_\Bbb C$. It is a union of singletons, and each singleton is an affine variety because $\{n\} = V(x-n)$. However, $\Bbb Z$ is not an affine variety. (Why?)